# Rename Android App but let users search with old app name in playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to rename an App which is already in playstore. Could i do something about, finding my app even when user's type in the old App name instead of new one?

Note : I am not changing the package name of the app.

Comment: Don't change package name 'cos you cannot update your app. You can put keyword with old name in new name's description

Comment: [suggestion] 1- type in your app description that you have change the app name and mention the old name in the desc, 2- also you can create  a campaign with google ads engines, and set the in meta data or keywords the new and old app name. i think this may help you

Comment: You must not change the package name! That's a very bad idea from @mehul Then you can't update your app, so the package name must stay the same once you've published your app in the Play Store.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions. I am not changing the App package name. I am only looking into changing App name. @AbuQauod Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you could follow the google's answer. Change your app description with your search keywords.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new name in your source, but in store listing, app name can be as follows:

> *New Name* (formerly *Old Name*)

After installing the app, a user would only get new app name as defined in the source.

App Name length has been extended from 30 chars to **50 chars**, so that should be enough.

This way your app would show up even when the users are searching using the old name.

Another thing is that the users would trust that they are using the same app but with just a different name.